# Voice calling from websites, user responding

Tags: linux, voice

I'm working on a system which needs to do the following:

(from linux)
* Call a user by phone
* Tell the user some action is required
* Give the user a choice and allow him to select based on his choice:
* Then based on the entry, run a command

- ex:  "Your attention is required because something is wrong.  To implement solution Alpha, press 1.  To implement solution Beta, press 2"
- (user press 1):  "Ok, solution Alpha is now in effect"

Of course this needs to be done from a website.  I am sure there are services which do this, what are some?

Thanks

Comment: The keyword you're probably looking for is [IVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response)

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I found Voiceshot which suits my purposes nicely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, thanks to Greg, I found Voiceshot and other companies on the web.  Gotta love it.

Thank you very much Greg.